# Cannot Import 'lsb' from partially initialized module 'stegano'

Tags: python, python-import, steganography

I'm trying to use the python module, Stegano to hide images within images. However, I'm getting an Import error whenever I try to run my code

`ImportError: cannot import name 'lsb' from partially initialized module 'stegano' (most likely due to a circular import)`

​
My code is as follows

```
import stegano
from stegano import lsb

secret = lsb.hide("stegano/1/picture1.png", "hello world!")
secret.save("stegano/1/picture1steg.png")
print(lsb.reveal("stegano/1/picture1steg.png")
```

I've looked into circular imports, and I don't think that's the issue as Stegano is imported before it's called upon?

This has really stumped me as I've never come across this issue before, and I've got a decent amount of experience with python, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You are not allowed to import the same package twice (as you do) because it runs some initialization. Try to remove the first line of your script.